# Big SPA with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-redux, single-page-application

I'm developing web applications using Meteor & React.js.
**I need your advice.**

The question is: ***how can I build a very large single-page application on Meteor?***

I'm faced with problems such as performance, the weight of the js and css files (I have a lot of components).
Are there ways to separate components and load any components only when necessary (when the user performs any actions)?

There is also an idea to create a single-page application that will have several sub-applications separate from each other. For example, the user clicks on the icon of the sub-application and in the main block "content" opens the sub-application and it all happens inside a single-page application.
The idea is that each sub-application is hosted on separate servers and has an individual database, backend and frontend.
Is it possible to do this with an iframe or is it a bad idea?
*It is important that all these sub-applications can interact with each other through the parent application.*

I await your advice and ideas. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first part of your vast question, I think you could look into the dynamic imports. Yes, you can separate one big App into smaller components or groups of components and only load "on demand" without them being part of the initial bundle: https://blog.meteor.com/dynamic-imports-in-meteor-1-5-c6130419c3cd

[image]

In the picture, startup = "general" bundle, async is for dynamic loads. If you have a lot of CSS ... then you have too much CSS and you should probably only have a framework CSS like Bootstrap and a theming CSS and ... if you use react you could add programatic inline styling.

For the second part of your question, if you want separate DB, servers and apps ... I don't really see the connection with the first question / environment. Do you mean kind of Dashboard where you have links (buttons) to various features/apps? Like in Salesforce or any other CRM or like in Firebase etc?
Managing multiple apps could be a nightmare. Making multiple apps interact ... it is a nightmare unless they have the same DB so you can share data and states. So ... if you are in the situation to show let's say yahoo email and gmail in the same "portal", I believe iframe would be your best option considering that those two platforms share 0 resources and data.

Let me ask you please, where / how do you see performance issues? Do you use something like Kadira for monitoring? Do you have a lot of pub/subs? Do you use Redux to store your local data? Do you use pagination where is the case? In theory the number of components and CSS is trivial given the compression and today LTE speeds on mobile. I also build a  full size social platform with feeds and chat etc with Meteor/React and I only have 3 publication with 25 initial documents each. Would you know your load in terms of number of pub * documents?

Comment: How can I make it so that my sub-apps are on separate servers?

Comment: You mean other Meteor apps that don't "talk" with your main Meteor App? I think Iframe would be good enough if you load the other apps like 1 by 1 and no need for 3-4 on the screen at the same time. This unless you want to send "away" from your main App. You could also use subdomains: ex: https://app1.maindomain.com, https://app2.maindomain.com, https://app3.maindomain.com and route to them from the main app.  TO be continued ...

Comment: Within those apps you can follow a "large picture" URL scheme to move from one app to the other and while routing you can save address, params and scroll of the previous page (the one you are leaving) so that you always come back to the same experience. You could use a REST or DDP interface for a single sign on unless you use the same DB for all Apps. Sorry but your questions tend to be a little vague and open.